# Bad archive mirror error when installing Kali 2016 64 bits

Tags: kali-linux, repository

This is the **error** I get during **graphical installation** from live USB on **64 bits v2016 Kali** version:

```
Configure the package manager
Bad archive mirror
An error has been detected while trying to use the specified Debian archive mirror.
```

Screenshot:
[image: Kali Linux live v2016 installation error]

Any other **country mirror** yields the same error.
Even changing the original `sources.list` file:

```
root@kali:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

To a newer one:

```
root@kali:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
#deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

... does not solve the problem neither.
The file `/var/log/syslog` seems not to show any mirror or repositories info (I can post it anyway if requested).

**Tested**:

- Kali Live v2016.1.
- Kali Live v2016.2.
- On two computers: a portable Lenovo G50-45 and a desktop rather old HP Compaq.
- Tested booting both USB and DVD live versions.

The [Kali Forums](https://forums.kali.org) don't show the solution, or I have not been able to find it.

How could I **solve** this `Bad archive mirror` error?

Answer (score 4):

Got same problem recently. Kali forums show the solution [actually](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?3313-Bad-archive-mirror-How-to-solve-this-one&p=6155&viewfull=1#post6155). 
Press "Go Back", then "Yes" (to skip configuring package manager step) and then, after you log into system, just update through terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?2756-Can-t-install-mini-iso-Bad-Archive-Mirror&highlight=archive%20mirror), another solution would be changing the name server to Google's ones:

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: Why should it make any difference? Internet seems to be working anyway.

Comment: Nope. In my case, using `192.168.1.1`, the router's DNS IP, blocked the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with certain gigabyte Ethernet cards kali not able to install ipv4
dhcp defaults to ipv6
In my case Found a walk around for this error .. plugin usb wifi adapter go into bios disable onboard LAN.. unplug Ethernet cable
reinstall kali linux  setup will ask for wifi password done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just select "Go back" and then it asks "No mirrors selected?" and then choose "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, from [Debian Mail-Forum](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/06/msg00420.html):

```
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect
```